# dataframe delete row with value of a categorical field above threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
   id    speed    mode
0   3    21        car
1   2    17        walk
2   4    34        car
3   5    7         walk
4   3    10        car
```

How do I delete rows for which the `speed` of `walk mode` is above 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change thinking - select all rows not `walk` or less equal like `10` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['mode'].ne('walk') | df['speed'].le(10)]
print (df)
   id  speed  mode
0   3     21   car
2   4     34   car
3   5      7  walk
4   3     10   car
```